# Most efficient way to parse dataset generated using petastorm from parquet

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-s3, petastorm

Versions : Python3.7.13, Tensorflow-2.9.1, Petastorm-0.12.1

I'm trying to implement data loading framework that creates tf.data.Dataset from parquet stored in S3 using petastorm.

Creating dataset as follows:

```
cols = [col1_nm, col2_nm, ...]
def parse(e):
    x_features = []
    for c in cols:
        x_features.append(getattr(e,c))
    X = tf.stack(x_features, axis=1)
    y = getattr(e, 'target')
    return X, y

with make_batch_reader(s3_paths, schema_fields=cols+['target']) as reader:
    dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(reader).map(parse)
    for e in dataset.take(3):
        print(e)
```

All is well but want to know if there are alternative(more efficient and maintainable) way.

before parsing dataset is of type `DatasetV1Adapter` and each element(e) in dataset (obtained via dataset.take(1)) is of type `inferred_schema_view` which consist of `EagerTensor` for each feature.

I've tried using index to split X, y however reading last element via [-1] does not return target's eager tensor.

Comment: Could you include the `print(e)` output in your question ?